# Do HMONITORs need to be released? If so, how?

Tags: winapi, memory-leaks, multiple-monitors

Several multiple-monitor API functions (eg, [MonitorFromRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145063%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) return a HMONITOR handle to the monitor in question. I have been unable to find the function to free this handle - does it need to be freed, and if so, how should I free it?

Comment: since you can't create them it seems unlikely that you'd be expected to destroy them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The SDK docs *always* explicitly mention how a handle needs to be released.  Nothing for HMONITOR, you are just getting a handle to an internal object that's around anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft's [Example program](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162826%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) doesn't try to free the handle. While their examples might not be perfect, they are a good indication of the way a function is meant to be used.